# No sound in USB headphones using fedora 16

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

The volume control buttons on the usb headphone work, they can increment or decrement the system sound.
However the **headphone have no sound**. How to make it work?

kernel 3.2, pusleaudio is used by default.

Comment: What do you get when you run `lspci | grep Audio`?

Comment: @jilen what gui are you using? or did you want a command line process? I can answer for KDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis of the problem is you have to change which sound card is being used. How to do this depends on whether you are using a gui or something else. I know next to nothing about pulse audio so I can't help with directions directly for that. But if you're using KDE you can open your "K" menu -> system settings -> multimedia -> phonon -> Audio Hardware setup tab, which should have a drop down for selecting your audio card. Any sound applications running may need to be restarted. You may have to install phonon first.
[image: screenshot]